# Flagged posts deleted posts shading not in line

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flag-history

[image]

You can see in the image above that the shading that appears if a post has been deleted is not in line with the vote count.

Looks like removing the `margin-top` and reducing the `line-height` from the `answer-link` class fixes it, but I'm not sure about compatibility issues/breaking other things on the site.

Comment: True, but that's the least of the problems with this page. IMO it needs a serious face-lift. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard True, but until then - might as well fix this ;p

Comment: @ShadowWizard The update to the design has removed this bug - what should I do? Flag for mod to add [tag:status-norepro]?

Comment: Cool! [tag:status-completed] fits more, it doesn't matter that it's only a "side effect". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the recent design update has removed this bug!

[image]